# How to share a list of objects without giving ability to modify their state?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class **StockMarket** which has a list of **Companies**.

```
class StockMarket : IStock
{
    private static List<IObserverPush> observersPush;
    private static List<IObserverPull> observersPull;
    public static List<Company> Companies { get; private set; }

    public StockMarket()
    {
        observersPush = new List<IObserverPush>();
        observersPull = new List<IObserverPull>();

        Companies = new List<Company>() { new Company("Unilever", "UNA", 47.72, 0.77, 1.63, -3.45, "135B"),
                                            new Company("ING Groep", "INGA", 13.40, -0.07, -0.50, -12.38, "60.4B"),
                                            new Company("ArcelorMittal", "MT", 29.50, 0.14, 0.48, 36.05, "54.6B"),
                                            new Company("ASML Holding", "ASML", 167.40, 2.00, 1.21, 36.49, "53.3B"),
                                            new Company("Heineken", "HEIA", 87.66, -0.02, -0.02, 2.80, "49B"),
                                            new Company("RELX", "REN", 18.15, 0.17, 0.95, -0.22, "38.9B"),
                                            new Company("Philips", "PHIA", 35.49, 0.17, 0.47, 7.61, "33.3B"),
                                            new Company("Unibail Rodamco", "UL", 196.40, -0.15, -0.08, -16.78, "20.3B"),
                                            new Company("Akzo Nobel", "AKZA", 75.68, -0.16, -0.21, 0.33, "19.4B"),
                                            new Company("Altice", "ATC", 7.58, 0.16, 2.16, -66.30, "17.6B")};

        Thread thread = new Thread(SimulateMarket);
        thread.Start();
    }
    public void Subscribe(IObserverPull o)
    {
        observersPull.Add(o);
        o.UpdateMarket();
    }
    public void Unsubscribe(IObserverPull o)
    {
        observersPull.Remove(o);
    }
    public void Subscribe(IObserverPush o)
    {
        observersPush.Add(o);
        o.UpdateMarket(Companies);
    }
    public void Unsubscribe(IObserverPush o)
    {
        observersPush.Remove(o);
    }
    public void NotifyObservers()
    {
        foreach(IObserverPush o in observersPush)
        {
            o.UpdateMarket(Companies);
        }

        foreach(IObserverPull o in observersPull)
        {
            o.UpdateMarket();
        }
    }

    public void SimulateMarket()
    {
        while(observersPush.Count + observersPull.Count > 0)
        {
            //randomly change property values of companies
            //and notify the observers about the changes
        }
    }
}
```

**Company** class has some properties.

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Symbol { get; private set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Change { get; set; }
    public double ChangePercentageDay { get; set; }
    public double ChangePercentageYear { get; set; }
    public string Capital { get; private set; }

    public Company(string name, string symbol, double price, double change, double changePercentageDay, 
                    double changePercentageYear, string capital)
    {
        Name = name;
        Symbol = symbol;
        Price = price;
        Change = change;
        ChangePercentageDay = changePercentageDay;
        ChangePercentageYear = changePercentageYear;
        Capital = capital;
    }
}
```

The **Forms** have references to the **StockMarket** and they use it to retrieve data about the companies and to display it.

**Form 1**

```
public partial class ConcreteObserverPush : Form, IObserverPush
{
    private StockMarket stockMarket;
    public ConcreteObserverPush()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stockMarket = new StockMarket();
        stockMarket.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void UpdateMarket(List<Company> companies)
    {
        stockMarketListView.Items.Clear();

        foreach(Company c in companies)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(c.Symbol);
            item.SubItems.Add(c.Price.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(c.Change.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(c.ChangePercentageDay.ToString() + "%");
            stockMarketListView.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void ConcreteObserverPush_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        stockMarket.Unsubscribe(this);
    }
}
```

**Form 2**

```
public partial class ConcreteObserverPull : Form, IObserverPull
{
    private StockMarket stockMarket;
    public ConcreteObserverPull()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stockMarket = new StockMarket();
        stockMarket.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void UpdateMarket()
    {
        stockMarketListView.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Company c in StockMarket.Companies)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(c.Symbol);
            item.SubItems.Add(c.Name);
            item.SubItems.Add(c.Price.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(c.Change.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(c.ChangePercentageDay.ToString() + "%");
            item.SubItems.Add(c.ChangePercentageYear.ToString() + "%");
            item.SubItems.Add(c.Capital);
            stockMarketListView.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void ConcreteObserverPull_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        stockMarket.Unsubscribe(this);
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the **Form** gets the list of companies through the property on **StockMarket** it can change their state. However, I want only StockMarket to have the ability to change the state of the company.

So what would be the best way to share **Company** state with **Form** when requested and preventing the **Form** from modifying it.

I know that a possible solution would be to return clones of **Company** objects, but I believe there should be a better solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what you exactly want to convey with the term 'State'?

Comment: what do you mean by `Change their state` ? Your code doesn't modify the class neither it's sub items such as the `List<T>`

Comment: As you said, `Company` should be an immutable object and have methods in `StockMarket` that creates `Company`'s when modified and delete old ones before adding the new one (or something to that effect).

Comment: I'm pretty sure Eric Lippert would answer this with "Make `Company` an immutable type`. Any changes should result in a new object."

Comment: @itsme86, can you explain please, I am eager

Comment: Sure. What I mean is don't provide setters on properties in `Company`. For example, if you want to change a company's price, you would create a new object for the company with the new price and then discard the old object. Since the stockmarket object controls the list, you can be assured (barring reflection of course) that other objects can't modify any companies in the list.

Comment: As one answer suggests, remove set property. :-)
Also, make all the public variables/properties in Company to private.

Comment: @itsme86 , where does the term `Change their state` means here?

Comment: By "change their state" I mean changing the property values.

Comment: @PoladSamadzada , but your code is not doing that anywhere ?

Comment: @ArpitGupta If I remove setters then I am also not able to change the values from StockMarket.

Comment: @zackraiyan Yes I didn't put the whole code in order to keep it simple, but I think the idea is clear.

Comment: @PoladSamadzada Yes, that's right. You would create a new company object with the new values and replace the old object in the list with the new one.

Comment: no the idea wasn't clear at all,  you should be greatful to the 1/2 guys who understood it

Comment: @zackraiyan The state of an object commonly refers to property values. I don't fault OP for using that terminology. Consider this something you've learned today. https://dzone.com/articles/stateful-or-stateless-classes

Comment: I appreciate your help guys. I can post the whole code if that would be more convenient for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general gist of this would be to make your `Company` object immutable. Then you would add methods to the StockMarket object to manipulate the Company list and replace entries with new ones when you want to change a value.

Here's a quick example put together in LINQPad of making the `Company` class immutable and adding an `UpdatePrice` method to the `StockMarket` class.

Whether you want to be able to manipulate the `Companies` property from outside the `StockMarket` can be handled by returning the list as `ReadOnlyCollection` so that it's size can't be manipulated by a consumer.

```
void Main()
{
    var sm = new StockMarket();
    sm.Companies.Add(new Company("Test", "TST", 50, 0));
    sm.UpdatePrice("Test", 45);
    var testCompany = sm.Companies.First(x => x.Name == "Test");
    Console.WriteLine($"{testCompany.Name},{testCompany.Symbol},{testCompany.Price},{testCompany.Change}");
    //Output: Test,TST,45,-5
}

class StockMarket
{
    public List<Company> Companies { get; private set; } = new List<Company>();

    public void UpdatePrice(string name, double price) {
        var index = Companies.FindIndex(x => x.Name == name);
        if(index >= 0)
        {
            var previous = Companies[index];
            Companies[index] = new Company(previous.Name, previous.Symbol, price, price - previous.Price);
        }
    }
}

class Company
{
    public Company(string name, string symbol, double price, double change) {
        Name = name;
        Symbol = symbol;
        Price = price;
        Change = change;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Symbol { get; }
    public double Price { get; }
    public double Change { get; }
    ///...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But does it prevent the consumers from changing the property values of the companies? Because it seems like the consumers still can retrieve the references to the actual objects.

Comment: The properties are get only in this example, so they can't be changed (with exceptions-like the use of reflection).

Comment: Oh, I see. So when StockMarket object wants to change some properties of a Company object it needs to create a new Company object and put it in a place of an old one. And in order to prevent the consumer to change the list I can return it as a ReadOnlyCollection, is that right?

Comment: That's the idea of it, yes. It's a little cumbersome as C# doesn't have a lot of good sugar for dealing with immutability. Maybe with record types in C# 8 we'll have an easier go of it.

Comment: For now, this one is the best solution to my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: @PoladSamadzada If the answer works for you, please mark it accepted and feel free to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a solution:

Create the Company class as a Private Inner Class inside of the StockMarket class, that way it'd only be accessible inside of it, and then provide an interface that only includes the get of all the properties and make Company implement it. You would have to make StockMarket's Company list to be the Interface's type.

Any modification you'd have to do you'd do it by casting the interface's List objects into the original class type.

Example:

```
class Program
{
    public static StockMarket stockMarket = new StockMarket();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}

public interface ICompany
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class StockMarket
{
    public StockMarket()
    {
        Companies = SomeWildFunctionThatRetrievesAllCompanies();
    }

    public void OneWildFunctionThatModifiesACompany()
    {
        Company dunno = (Company)Companies[0];
        dunno.Name = "Modification Made Possible";
    }

    private List<ICompany> SomeWildFunctionThatRetrievesAllCompanies()
    {
        return new List<ICompany>(new List<Company>());
    }

    public List<ICompany> Companies { get; private set; }

    private class Company : ICompany
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty good solution. It may be worth setting the access level on the Company class' property setters to private to avoid people changing the properties by first casting to `dynamic`.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the solution, maybe because I couldn't explain my problem properly. I am going to edit my post, I'll put the whole code. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome, I'll try to help you as far as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Company
{
    public Company(Type type,string name,string symbol,double price, double change)
    {
        if (type.Name == "StockMarket")
        {
            Name = name;
            Symbol = symbol;
            Price = price;
            Change = change;
        }

    }
    private string Name { get; set;  }
    private string Symbol { get;  set; }
    private double Price { get; set; }
    private double Change { get; set; }
    ///...
}
```

This will allow you to change the state only if the type is StockMarket
like:

```
class StockMarket
{
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public StockMarket()
    {
        Companies = new List<Company>();

    }
    public StockMarket someMethod()
    {

        //You can change the state here
        StockMarket s = new StockMarket();
        s.Companies.Add(new Company(this.GetType(), "aa", "_", 123, 1234));
        return s;
    }
    //...
}
```

Now you cannot change the state here:

```
public partial class Observer: Form
{
    private StockMarket stockMarket;

    public ConcreteObserverPull()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       stockMarket = new StockMarket();
     //Here you cannot change the state
       stockMarket.Companies.Add(new Company(this.GetType(), "aa", "_", 123,12)); 


    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: But the consumer can put a fake object of type StockMarket when it creates a new Company object. Also, it is not quite about my problem. I edited my post and I hope I was able to make it more clear. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I don't know C#, but as an idea, you can wrap returned entities with decorator or proxy, which will throw an exception in case of trying to modify state of a company.

Comment: Why throw an exception when you could just not expose any members for modification in the first place?

Comment: Yes, it's also possible way, it depends from needs.

Answer (score -3):

Returning clones with fields set as readonly is the safest way to go.

Comment: Did you even understand the question ?